# Define one single background size on SASS class

Tags: css, sass

So I have the following code:

```
.has-background-graphic
  &-is-25
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, whitesmoke 25%, transparent), url('/liuzishan/liuzishan1612/liuzishan161200017/66848202-abstract-graphic-design-a-sense-of-science-and-technology-background-.jpg')
    background-size: cover
    background-position: center
  &-is-50
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, whitesmoke 50%, transparent), url('/uploads/meta/internal-media-file/2020/techlash-2020-1600345019.jpg')
    background-size: cover
    background-position: center
  &-is-75
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, whitesmoke 75%, transparent), url('/uploads/meta/internal-media-file/2020/tgi-covid-19-study-wave-2-1595432491.jpg')
    background-size: cover
    background-position: center
```

With `SASS`, is it possible to define `background-size` and `background-position` without me having to repeat myself in very `-` extension?

Please note, I don't have `has-background-graphic` define anywhere, but I do have the following defined:

- `has-background-graphic-is-25`
- `has-background-graphic-is-50`
- `has-background-graphic-is-75`

All help would be appreciated!

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question, but can't you just move `background-size` and `background-position` to `.has-background-graphic`, and then only have the images defined in each `-is-`?

Comment: You can use [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) to define common styles in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a simple *starts with* [CSS selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_begin.asp). No SASS needed, but this is the SASS syntax:

```
[class^="has-background-graphic"]
    background-size: cover
    background-position: center
```

You can use a [Sass Map](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/values/maps) for this:

```
/* Define your sizes and urls here */
$sizes: ("25": "/liuzishan/liuzishan1612/liuzishan161200017/66848202-abstract-graphic-design-a-sense-of-science-and-technology-background-.jpg", "50": "/uploads/meta/internal-media-file/2020/techlash-2020-1600345019.jpg", "75": "/uploads/meta/internal-media-file/2020/tgi-covid-19-study-wave-2-1595432491.jpg")

.has-background-graphic
  /* Loop through each size and url */
  @each $size, $url in $sizes
    &-is-#{$size}
      background-image: linear-gradient(to right, whitesmoke #{$size}#{"%"}, transparent), url("#{$url}")
      background-size: cover
      background-position: center
```

This will compile to:

```
.has-background-graphic-is-25 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, whitesmoke 25%, transparent), url("/liuzishan/liuzishan1612/liuzishan161200017/66848202-abstract-graphic-design-a-sense-of-science-and-technology-background-.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
.has-background-graphic-is-50 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, whitesmoke 50%, transparent), url("/uploads/meta/internal-media-file/2020/techlash-2020-1600345019.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
.has-background-graphic-is-75 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, whitesmoke 75%, transparent), url("/uploads/meta/internal-media-file/2020/tgi-covid-19-study-wave-2-1595432491.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

Note! You need to escape the `%`, so that's why `#{"%"}` is like that in the `background-image` property.

Comment: if I have a `.sass` file, how do I call the `class=` selector?

Comment: What I gave you would work in your SASS file.

Comment: Thanks so much! Works perfectly and I learned a new approach to loop through inside SASS.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a mixin if you want to be more flexible about the values

```
@mixin background($image, $size, $position)
    background-image: $image
    background-size: $size
    background-position: $position

.has-background-graphic
    &-is-25
        @include background((linear-gradient(to right, whitesmoke 25%, transparent), url('/liuzishan/liuzishan1612/liuzishan161200017/66848202-abstract-graphic-design-a-sense-of-science-and-technology-background-.jpg')), cover, center)
    &-is-50
        @include background((linear-gradient(to right, whitesmoke 50%, transparent), url('/uploads/meta/internal-media-file/2020/techlash-2020-1600345019.jpg')), cover, center)
    &-is-75
        @include background((linear-gradient(to right, whitesmoke 75%, transparent), url('/uploads/meta/internal-media-file/2020/tgi-covid-19-study-wave-2-1595432491.jpg')), cover, center)
```

You can put the parameters in multiple lines if you're using scss instead of sass.